# Octomap basic tutorial

Tags: ros, octomap, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to octomaps. I could not find any tutorials. Could some one kindly help me to start ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66269/octomap-basic-tutorial/) by [kk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5289/kk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2013-06-29

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no step by step tutorials, but you are welcome to write some ;) Check http://octomap.github.io/ for information, there is the paper linked there with all details explained and also a mailing list for further questions regarding OctoMap (+a few answers already).

For an introduction you could also have a look at the ROSCon talk (slides + video) about OctoMap:
http://roscon.ros.org/2013/?page_id=14

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5289/kk/) on 2013-07-04**:
Hi thank you for the reply. I was able to create 3d maps of the simulated environment from morse. The ROSCon talk was really good and very useful. And yes definitely i will create a tutorial as soon as i have learnt the basics myself ;-p  A tutorial would help lot many people interested in octomap.

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-01-09**:
Look forward to the tutorial!